# Why doesn't java.exe return error code on RuntimeException?

Tags: java

I run `java.exe` from a batch file and my java app (which is a LibGDX app, btw) always returns `0` as a return code (to the command prompt), even when the app crashes.

**My question is this:** why doesn't Java return some kind of an error code (like error code 1), and is it possible to somehow tell java to return an error code on e.g. `RuntimeException`?

**My problem is this:** in my batch file, I have the following code:

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ( 
   @echo on
   echo Batch execution finished with error: %errorlevel%
   pause
)
```

However, this code never gets executed, and hence my command prompt closes when app finishes. However, I would like it to remain open if the app crashes so that I can analyze the error.

Note that I can't arbitrarily call `System.exit(1)` on `RuntimeException` since my app uses LibGDX which runs in a separate thread over which I have no control. In other words, I can't catch RuntimeException thrown from that thread in my `main()` method.

Comment: You can add an explicit return error code by adding `System.exit(int status)` to `RuntimeException`s you throw yourself. It will of course not affect `Exception`s that are not handled in your code.

Comment: Yes, I know that, however I can't do that in my LibGDX app because it runs in another thread over which I have no control.

Comment: Please include that in your question. The question is incomplete without that

Comment: [java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html)

Comment: @Abra: I could use that, if I had access to the thread, which I don't (it's an anonymous thread anyway). I can't use Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler neither, since there are all kinds of threads in my app (over some I have control, over some not), and I can't just call System.exit(1) from such a handler for any thread.

Comment: If the *main thread* throws an exception, the Java process absolutely will exit with a nonzero status code.  If two non-main threads are running, and one throws an exception, but the other one completes a minute later with no exceptions, what would you expect Java to do?

Comment: @VGR: Wrong, java returns 0 on RuntimeException in "main thread" (or any other thread). Java terminates when first thread throws RuntimeException, regardless if it is main or not (how would you define main thread anyway? Java app will run until any of its threads are running and none have thrown an exception).

Comment: I just tried it.  It really does return a nonzero status.  And the “main thread” is the thread which executes the `main` method.  If the `main` method throws an exception, the Java process returns a nonzero status.  Try it for yourself.  My point is that there is no meaningful way for Java to decide which *other* threads should determine exit status.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your code is never explicitly calling `System.exit(someReturnCode)`.

Without an explicit call, you end up with a default `System.exit(0)` happening at some point.

It doesn't matter what your setup is: unless you call that method, the RC will always be 0!

As implied by the comments, your *only* hope is that by adding a [UncaughtExceptionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) you find a way to have *your* code being notified about exceptions in other places.

Comment: True, I never call System.exit(), only Gdx.app.exit(), which is the correct way to close a libgdx app. However, when a runtime exception occurs, I have no control over it and don't get to call System.exit() at all. My question is: is there a way to detect RuntimeException from my batch file? I guess I can always parse the output, but that is tedious, there must be some more elegant way!

Comment: @Betalord See my updates. If that doesn't help, then there is no other way.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to set a default uncaught exception handler.  This will handle any exception on any application thread that propagates out of `run()` or `main()`.

See the javadocs for [`Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)) and the 
[`Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) interface.

If you read the javadocs, you will see that `setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` is a `static` method.  You don't call it for every thread.  You call it once ... for all threads.

A handler is passed the `Thread` object for the thread that is about to terminate, and can be coded to work out if it is appropriate to call `System.exit` with a non-zero exit code ... or not.  For example, it decide  this based on the thread's name, or the thread's ThreadGroup or by examining the exception stacktrace to work out which class supplied the `run()` method.

In fact, when you install a default uncaught exception handler, you are replacing the handler installed by the Java runtime ... which prints a stacktrace and (in the case of the `main()` thread) calls `System.exit(0)` .

Alternatively, there is a `setUncaughtExceptionHandler` method that sets a handler on a specific thread.  If you need to find a specific thread, then you can do that by traversing the thread tree from the root `ThreadGroup`.

Comment: Like I answered in one of the comments, my app is using many threads (as well as libgdx library, which I believe uses separate threads for rendering, audio, and main processing), so I can't simply call System.exit(1) on whichever thread that crashes (sometimes I don't care if one specific thread crashes, while the main rendering thread still runs). Checking which thread has caused the RuntimeException might also be tedious or impossible, in case libgdx creates anonymous threads (which it does).

Comment: @Betalord - I wish you had actually read what I wrote.   The first sentence ... in fact.

Comment: Stephen: seems you didn't read what I wrote. I understand it's a static method, but you don't understand that I can't handle all the threads in the same way. I can't simply call System.exit(1) for any thread that crashes. Please read my previous comment again.

Comment: If you can't handle all threads the same way, then don't.  Either install a **non-default** handler on specific threads ... or code the generic handler to **work out** whether the thread is one that you should call `exit` on, or not.   And if you can't work it out (e.g. based on the thread name or something) then your problem is fundamentally unsolvable.

Comment: Well, my problem is not fundamentally unsolvable, since there are other ways how to approach it, like parsing through console output and searching for RuntimeException and such. However I did find out the name of the main libgdx thread (which is "LWJGL Application"), so I've attached a handler to that and it seems to work. Not exactly the solution I was searching for (what if libgdx changes name of the thread in one of the future updates, or something similar?), but it works.

Comment: *"... since there are other ways how to approach it"* - Such as?  Bear in mind you have precluded most of them.

Comment: _"...like parsing through console output and searching for RuntimeException"_

Comment: That does not solve the problem that you stated in the question. The problem you states was to get Java to set a non-zero exit code.